# Modifying this scrolling nav menu script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a noob and for a school project I was trying to create a single page site that had a static nav menu at the top that always stayed there and I wanted it to do an animated scroll effect when you click it's link.  Someone here made this for me and it works perfect.

However, you notice it says `.top` - 98 and that is because my nav is 98px tall so that it doesn't cut off the section it's jumping to.

Now that I am getting into media queries, I may increase the height of that nav at certain breaks.  So I am wondering, **is it possible to change this from 98 to some sort of [nav current height] variable?  So that it will work regardless of what the height of my nav is?**

Thanks in advance!!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("nav a").on('click', function() {
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: ($(link).offset().top - 98)
    }, 'slow');
    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: ($(link).offset().top - $('nav').height())},'slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that

```
scrollBarFunc = function(){
    var myNavHeight = $("#myselectorId").height();  //just put here your id or class 

    $("nav a").on('click',function(){
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: ($(link).offset().top - myNavHeight)},'slow');
        return false;
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    scrollBarFunc();
});
$(window).resize(function(){
    scrollBarFunc();  //recall function to work when you resize 
});
```

Comment: Maybe I'll try this too - do you think the simpler one above could give me issues in some instances?

Comment: @user4340635 both are correct, my is with function when you can real resize and your browser will get desired height of nav. One mark as "correct anwser" is gonna work only on refresh on each resize when change height nav